# I want to update Value but supervisor id update not properly it's update only first value where get employee_id

Tags: php, laravel

here I get supervisor id
[image]

I want to update all supervisor IDs where employee_id and employee are equal. When i  update this value it's just an update of the single value for WorkingHierarchys Table. I try too much but I can't resolve this.
[image]
here update only one value for employee

here updated code

```
                    foreach($supervisors as $key=>$supervisor){
                        $work_hiechye['supervisor_id']=$supervisor;
                        $work_hiechye['employee_id']=$employee;
                        WorkingHierarchy::where('employee_id',$employee)->update($work_hiechye);


                    }
```

Comment: You are trying to update all fields where employee_id is equal with employee into a foreach loop. It is updating all the fields where the condition is right with every value from the supervisor array, and it eventually will stop at the last one, which is 71 in your case.

Comment: how can I overcome this?

Comment: okay i try this then i feedback to you thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update the employee_id where the superviser_id is equal with $superviser and it will be something like this. I don't know your whole context, but what are you trying to do is not gone work.

```
foreach($supervisors as $supervisor) {
    WorkingHierarchy::where([ 'superviser_id' => $supervisor ])->update([ 'employee_id' => $employee ]);
}
```

Comment: it's remain same not updated supervisor id